# Can I use a 'continue' statement in a ternary operator?

Tags: c

How can I use a *continue* statement in a ternary operator?

```
for (i = 0; i < arr_size - 1; i++)
        {
                ar[i] == 1 || ar[i] == 2 || ar[i] == 3 ? count++ : continue;
        }
```

I can replace it like this.

```
for (i = 0; i < arr_size - 1; i++)
        {
                ar[i] == 1 || ar[i] == 2 || ar[i] == 3 ? count++ : count;
        }
```

Comment: The ternary operator requires expressions but `continue` isn't one. You'll probably want to use a normal `if ... else` statement instead.

Comment: `count += ar[i] < 4 && ar[i] > 0;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `continue` in this way as it is a **statement**, and the operands of the ternary operator must be a **expression**.

Like any operator, its result has a value which can be used in other expressions.  If it were allowed to use `continue` in the way you want, what would the value of the expression be?  It doesn't make sense to use in that way.

The ternary operator isn't appropriate for what you want.  It should be rewritten as an `if` statement:

```
if (ar[i] == 1 || ar[i] == 2 || ar[i] == 3) {
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Re “It doesn't make sense to use in that way”: Functions with return values have results that are values which can be used in other expressions, but they contain statements, and they might not return (due to `longjmp`, `exit`, and so on). So clearly it can make sense for an expression to contain statements. This incorrect reasoning is not necessary to answer the question; the conditional operator simply requires expressions for its operands, in the absence of language extensions, regardless of the reasons.

Answer (score 2):

[Ternary operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) have some special rules.

For example, you only can use **expressions** in these three parameters. But `continue;` is a complete sentence. So it can't work with ternary operators.

If you have to use ternary operators with *continue*, you can try this:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr_size - 1; i++)
        {
                bool flag = false;
                ar[i] == 1 || ar[i] == 2 || ar[i] == 3 ? count++ : (flag = true);
                if(flag) continue;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

See [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or some newer C standard.  Read also [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and study for inspiration the source code of *existing* [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) coded in C, such as [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/).

### Expressions and statements are different.

Code:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr_size - 1; i++)
{
    if (ar[i] == 1 || ar[i] == 2 || ar[i] == 3)
        count++;
    else
        continue;
}
```

Given that `else continue` is the last thing in the loop, you could omit it.

Hint: compile your C code with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler [invoked](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`.

**Read the documentation of your C compiler** (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) **and your debugger** (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)).

If so allowed, use static source code analysis tools like the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), or [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/), or [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) or the [DECODER](https://www.decoder-project.eu/) project.

(For both Frama-C and Bismon and [DECODER](https://www.decoder-project.eu/), contact me—in 2021—by email to *basile.starynkevitch@cea.fr*.)